# Cannot install Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04

Doenloaded the .deb package of Chrome from Google's site. The installation doesn't work when trying to install from the GUI. What's up with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome requires some missing dependencies as can be seen when trying to install from the terminal using `dpkg -i`. Prior to installing Chrome, run:

```
sudo apt-get install libindicator7 libappindicator1
```

After that, Chrome installation works fine.

Comment: Just had the issue myself on a fresh ubuntu built (17). The following dependencies were also needed `gconf-service-backend` `gconf-service` `gconf2-common` and `libgconf-2-4` - best call is to install from cmd line so one can see error if any. Pretty poor UX on Ubuntu part for not showing errors in the GUI.

Comment: Just running this won't install Chrome.

Comment: Still having The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 `google-chrome-stable : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.35) but 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.14 is to be installed`

Answer (score 5):

Its very simple to install google chrome on ubuntu . Type the following commands in the terminal

**Step 1 :** Download the latest Google Chrome .deb package with wget:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**Step 2** : Install the Google Chrome .deb package

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You'll have to manually upgrade it each time like this since you don't use a package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Update the packages first in Ubuntu by below command.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install Required Dependices for Google Chrome as shown below.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d libxss1 libgconf2-4 libappindicator1 libindicator7
```

Download the Google Chrome command using below command.

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

still during installation if you get some error that some dependency is not installed run the below command and it will install all required dependencies.

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Now let's go ahead and install Google Chrome by below command.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

And its done....

To open it just run below command command

```
$ google-chrome
```

Answer (score -1):

You can download the latest package of chrome [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/)

Install the package by clicking on it, or via the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

If you have issues, you may have to run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Alternatively you can use gdebi to install the .deb packages.
It's a lightweight application that is better at installing .deb packages, and is quicker as well. If there are dependencies, it notifies that as well.
To install it type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Once done you can right click on .deb file and select to open it with Gdeb

Answer (score -1):

```
    I face so many issue to install google chrome on Ubuntu 16.04. 
   finalyl, I successfully install google chrome on ubuntu by following commands:
    Step 1: $sudo apt-get install gdebi
    Step 2: wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

    Step 3: In same directory where you have download package or give path in command
        $sudo gdebi google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

    installed chrome successfully.
```

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue. on running google-chrome from terminal, found that it need new version of NSS. Chrome 62 need NSS>=3.26. So installed libnss3.

```
$google-chrome
```

[6999:7036:1113/200616.549496:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3
```

and it worked for me :)

Comment: Still having `The following packages have unmet dependencies: google-chrome-stable : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.35) but 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.14 is to be installed`